# How to bind a complex string type to Checkbox in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to bind a complex string value 'True' or 'False' to a checkbox i tried both these ways but neither seem to work:

**First Way:**

```
<EditForm Model="@Wrapper" FormName="BlogSettings" OnValidSubmit="@SaveBlogSettingsAsync" style="width: 100%" novalidate>
<DataAnnotationsValidator />

    @foreach(var item in Wrapper.BlogSettings)
    {
        <div>
        @if (item.Value.ToLower().Contains("true") | item.Value.ToLower().Contains("false"))
        {
                <InputCheckbox Value=@(Convert.ToBoolean(item.Value)) ValueChanged=@((v) => item.Value = v.ToString()) Label="@(Enum.GetName(item.Setting))" />
            }
            else
            {
            <FluentTextField Label="@(Enum.GetName(item.Setting))" TextFieldType="@TextFieldType.Text" @bind-Value="item.Value" Style="width: 100%" />                    
            }
     </div>
        
    }
     <FluentButton Type="@ButtonType.Submit" Style="width: 100%;  margin-top: 2rem;" Appearance="Appearance.Accent">Save</FluentButton>

</EditForm>
```

`InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputCheckbox requires a value for the 'ValueExpression' parameter. Normally this is provided automatically when using 'bind-Value'.`

**Second Way:**

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value:get="bool.Parse(item.Value)" @bind-Value:set="(val) => {item.Value = val.ToString();}" Label="@(Enum.GetName(item.Setting))" />
```

`ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a MethodCallExpression1 which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.`

`BlogSettings.razor.cs` :

```
partial class BlogSettings
{
    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "BlogSettings")]
    public BlogSettingsWrapper Wrapper { get; set; } = new();

    [Inject]
    public ISettingsService SettingsService { get; set; }
    private async Task SaveBlogSettingsAsync()
    {
        await SettingsService.SaveSettingsAsync(Wrapper.BlogSettings);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Wrapper.BlogSettings = SettingsService.GetSettings().OrderBy(bs => bs.Setting).ToList();          
    }
    public class BlogSettingsWrapper
    {
        public ICollection<BlogSetting> BlogSettings { get; set; } = [];
    }
}
```

`BlogSetting.cs` :

```
public class BlogSetting : BaseEntity
{
    public Setting Setting { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Is there an alternative way to do that? And what mistake am I doing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a lot of different data types, I'd specify it in the data source, rather than using complicated parse logic to figure it out.  My DB table would be: `SettingName nvarchar(50); SettingType nvarchar(50); Value nvarchar(MAX);`

I'd use an `object` instead of a string for my `Setting.Value`.  That way, I can throw whatever I want in there: date, float, etc.

In **unpacking** my values from my DataSource, I'd use a switch on the SettingType:

```
switch (DBsetting.SettingType){
     case "Int32": Setting.Value = Int32.Parse(DBsetting.Value);
         break;
     case "DateTime": Setting.Value = DateTime.Parse(DBsetting.Value);
         break;
}
```

In **displaying** each value, I can then use another switch on the type:

```
@foreach (var setting in Settings){
    if (setting.Value is Int32){
       <input type="number" @bind=setting.Value>
       return;
    }
    if (setting.Value is String){
          <input @bind=setting.Value>
         return;
    }
    if (setting.Value is Boolean){
          <input type="checkbox" checked="@setting.Value" > @setting.Name
          return;
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Note that I haven't checked this code.  You might have to do some tap-dancing to bind a float value to a string input or whatever, but that's a different issue.

There are probably more Blazor-y or more efficient C# ways of doing this, but I feel this code is very highly readable.  It should be clear 6 months from now what you were doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's what i did later, except i used Enums for data types, I'll use object as value type and use your logic as it seems more readable

Answer (score 0):

Create `ValueBool` in `BlogSetting`, use `bind-Value="@ValueBool"` and solve the conversion in "viewmodel". Decorate with `[JsonIgnore]` or create extra viewmodel for that...

```cs
    public class BlogSetting : BaseEntity
    {
        public Setting Setting { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        private bool valueBool;
        public bool ValueBool
        {
            get => valueBool;//maybe some conversion from string here if you need it
            set {
                Value= value.ToString();
                valueBool = value;
            }
        }
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

razor:

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@item.ValueBool"  Label="@(Enum.GetName(item.Setting))" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, do you have any other suggestions for handling different value types such as Date, float, string... Without creating a new Property (ValueBool, ValueDate...) For each one

Comment: I depends on your expectation and the purpose of such logic.. You can keep everything in original type and convert everything to string when the form is submitted.